# Date appears in Dataframe as None

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

1.-I want to create a data frame that contains a column with de date of today. But when I tried the result is the column with None´s

2.- I have tried with some library and parse, but it doesn´t work

3.- This is my code:

```
def tipo_uno():
    dt = datetime.datetime.now()
    ceros = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    df_ti = pd.DataFrame({'ID_KQI': ceros, 'FECHA_PROCESO': ceros, 'FECHA_CONTABLE':ceros, 'NUMERADOR':ceros, 'POBLACION_TOTAL':ceros, 'ID_INFORME':ceros, 'ID_ENTIDAD':ceros, 'ARCHIVO':arr_para_fr})
    df_ti = df_ti.set_index('ARCHIVO')
    fecha = print("{}/{}/{}".format(dt.day, dt.month, dt.year))
    df_ti.FECHA_PROCESO.replace( [0] , [fecha], inplace=True)
    return df_ti
```

tipo_uno()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print` in Python doesn't return anything, so you don't want to assign it. You want to use the `strftime` method to create a string representation of your time.

This will work:

```
def tipo_uno():
    ceros = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    df_ti = pd.DataFrame({'ID_KQI': ceros, 'FECHA_PROCESO': ceros, 'FECHA_CONTABLE':ceros, 'NUMERADOR':ceros, 'POBLACION_TOTAL':ceros, 'ID_INFORME':ceros, 'ID_ENTIDAD':ceros, 'ARCHIVO':'arr_para_fr'})
    df_ti = df_ti.set_index('ARCHIVO')
    fecha = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    df_ti.FECHA_PROCESO.replace( [0] , [fecha], inplace=True)
    return df_ti

tipo_uno()
```

Better still is to assign it directly, rather than first using a series of zeroes as a placeholder:

```
df_ti['FECHA_PROCESO'] = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Lastly note that the `inplace` parameter is slated for deprecation in future versions of Pandas. It is better to use assignment, so in your example:

```
df_ti.FECHA_PROCESO = df_ti.FECHA_PROCESO.replace([0], [fecha])
```